# WPF Change property of an object (that is a dependency property) in usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, inotifypropertychanged

I have a class

```
   class Export{
      TimeSpan SlowDownPosition{get; set;}
    }
```

Now this class is a dependency property of my usercontrol. And `SlowDownPosition` is bound to a TextBlock. I have a button that will reset the value to `zero`. But doing so doesn't update the UI, since `SlowDownPosition` is a property of a dependency property.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=TagMetaDataControl,Path=Export.SlowDownPosition}" />
<Button Content="X" Click="ResetAutoSlowPosition" />
```

On code behind

```
private void ResetAutoSlowPosition(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Export.SlowDownPosition = TimeSpan.Zero;
    }
```

Is there a way to update the UI without making `SlowDownPosition` itself a dependency property?

Comment: you used [inotifypropertychanged] tag, so you know about it, but you don't implement it in Export class. why?

Comment: @ASh because it's a datamodel; and implementing it on a usercontrol doesn't seem like the right approach

Comment: when don't bind control directly to datamodel. introduce a view model which implements INPC

Comment: @ASh yah that's the approach I'm probably gonna take, it's a very simple control, figured I could just do it without any viewmodel

Comment: "Is there a way to update the UI without making SlowDownPosition itself a dependency property?" Sure, simply make Export implement INotifyPropertChanged and fire the PropertyChanged event when SlowDownPosition changes. The Binding to `Export.SlowDownPosition` will be triggered then, and the UI magically updates.

Comment: There is no reason not to implement INPC on the model class...

Answer (score 1):

You can force the binding to refresh.

XAML:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock" Text="{Binding ElementName=TagMetaDataControl,Path=Export.SlowDownPosition}" />
```

Code Behind:

```
private void ResetAutoSlowPosition(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Export.SlowDownPosition = TimeSpan.Zero;
    MyTextBlock.GetBindingExpression(TextBlock.TextProperty).UpdateTarget();
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach I'll try it out

Comment: @SZTthis should be marked as the accepted answer. I totally forgot this way of updating binding targets. I will delete my answer.